# mongoose schema add new field dynamically, but undefined error?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

First of all sorry for my terrible english.

In Node.js, I use mongodb using mongoose.

```
const TestASchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  }
});
TestA = mongoose.model('TestA', TestASchema);
const TestBSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  }
});
TestB = mongoose.model('TestB', TestBSchema);
```

In test code,

```
mongoose.model('TestA').schema.add({
  abc: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  }
});
TestA = mongoose.model('TestA');

_testA = {
  name: 'TESTA'
};
testA = new TestA(_testA);

_testB = {
  name: 'TESTB'
};
testB = new TestB(_testB);
testA
.save()
.then(() => testB.save())
.then(() => done())
.catch(chainError => done(chainError));
```

and then,

```
const testB2 = new TestB({ name: 'TESTB2' });
const testB3 = new TestB({ name: 'TESTB3' });
testB2
.save()
.then(() => testB3.save())
.then(() => {
  //testA.update({ $pushAll: { values: [testB2, testB3] } });
  testA.set('abc', 'asdfasdf');
  testA
  .save()
  .then((savedTestA) => {
    console.log(savedTestA);
    done();
  });
});
```

it works good. and console log is

```
{ __v: 0,
  name: 'TESTA',
  abc: 'asdfasdf',
  testbsa: [],
  _id: 58d9fd904ae344082c38ccf2 }
```

THE PROBLEM is why i can not access using testA.abc but testA.set('abc', '...')?

If I set using testA.abc, not happened. also, console.log(testA.abc) is undefined.

The abc field is just my for my test, real field is testbsa. It's array so it is hard to set value using set function.

**1) How can i access using dot? ex) testA.abc
2) If Q1 is impossible, How can i PUSH the value some kind of set?
ex) testA.set('testbsa', values: [])**

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: There is no error message.
It doesn't comes out any error, but value is not changed.
Just I CAN NOT INSERT the value using dot
like testA.abc = 'TEST VALUE'

Comment: Have you considered inserting the "abc" field to your schema?

Comment: yes i am. i try to consider as my knowledge (?), it MUST insert dynamically because this is designed for mongoose plugin. no one knows what this field is. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved.

The point is where I register the mongoose plugin.

Once mongoose model is registered, there is no way to switch same model with newly registered plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This is super weird but if you JSON.stringify it and then JSON.parse you will be able to treat it as a normal object. Seems like a quicker workaround to be honest, although kinda stupid.